# For what $d$ does the sum $\sum_{i,j =1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+j)^{d/2}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

For some extra background, I am looking at the expected number of intersections of two random walks, and the calculation reduced to
$$\sum_{i,j =1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+j)^{d/2}}.$$

Due to the nature of random walks I expect the answer to be only for $d>4$, however I can only show that it diverges for $d\leq 2$ by using the trivial lower bound of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{d/2}}.$

Answer (score 2):

As I was writing this post I came up with the answer. We can see that for each $k$ there are $k$ different ways for $i+j=k$. That means we can rewrite
$$
\sum_{i,j =1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+j)^{d/2}}
=
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k^{d/2}}
\approx
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{d/2-1}}.$$
By Analysis 1 this only converges for $d>4$ and diverges for $d\leq 4$.

Comment: should be $\sum_{k=\color{red}{2}}^\infty \frac{k\color{red}{-1}}{k^{d/2}}$